# 2005 Chevy Suburban loud tap on hard acceleration

Tags: chevrolet, noise, acceleration, suburban

I have a 2005 Chevrolet Suburban 4WD 5.3 (208k miles) that has several loud taps when I accelerate moderately to hard. It only happens from slow or stop. I haven't been able to get the sound when flooring it after 20 mph.  The sound is coming what sounds like directly below the cab or a little forward. Can't isolate which side and don't see anything obvious underneath. I power braked (in gear, holding brake) and was able to get it to happen once. Only happens when in drive. Happens in 4 low also.

[Here is the video of it.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rolLqF-bXnQDWoJQwJ7sPBjF1-fY7biw/view?usp=sharing)  I accelerate on 2 occasions and you can hear it at 
 3 seconds and 17 seconds,

Any ideas what it could be?

EDIT: Not sure if this has any bearing on it but when inspecting ujoints,  [saw this on transfer case output to rear](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-0zierobcxY2gqqlNeVJEC4n_bV9ptQ6)

Comment: Judging by sound alone, it seems like one of the u-joints in either the front or rear drive shafts has gone bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the transfer case chain jumping. Put in a used transfer case and solved the issue.

Thanks for the help!